# android: pausing an activity until another finishes

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, workflow-activity

When my app starts, it checks to see if it has stored login credentials. if it doesn't, it starts another activity to prompt the user for those credentials. My problem is, that when the prompt activity is started, the first activity continues execution and ends up with null pointers because the prompt activity has not yet returned the needed data

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);

    promptForLoginInfo(); //method creates intent and starts activity

    displayCredentials(); //prints data to screen
}
```

the output reads: "null" because the program executes "displayCredentials()" before the login prompt activity returns.

Anyone have a clue what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "promptForLoginInfo()" method should be calling [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).  Your "displayCredentials()" method should not be called in the onCreate() method, but in the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method.

Comment: thank you. now that this problem is resolved ill move on to the next

Answer (score 1):

In promptForLoginInfo(); you need to start activityForResult.
then you need move  displayCredentials(); from onCreate to onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to check for stored credentials before calling displayCredentials()? If credentials are not found you can start activity by startActivityForResult() method and call displayCredentials() after your prompt activity finishes in onActivityResult().